# Is there any way to get google classroom form question insert title image URL

Tags: image, google-chrome, google-apps-script, title, github-classroom

I want to get the image url which is inserted when create a question into the classroom form.

Below is the code through we get the title , choices if available but i am not able to get the image url which is insert under the question title.

```
function getCourse() {
  var form = FormApp.openById(id);
  var formResponses = form.getItems();
  var type=formResponses[0].getType();
  var title = formResponses[0].getTitle();
  var image =formResponses[0].getImage();//no such method Logger.log(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That image is not available through the Forms Service, it's added through the `/viewresponse` source code which is generated some way by Google. You could get it by using the URL Fetch Service (`UrlFetchApp`).

Related

- [How can I scrape text and images from a random web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49341918/1595451)
- [(javascript / google scripts) How to get the title of a page encoded with iso-8859-1 so that the title will display correctly in my utf-8 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16943281/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

var blob = questionType.getImage();
   var b64 = blob.getContentType() + ';base64,'+ Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  var html = "data:" + b64 ;